# Creating a responsive, variable-height, variable-width grid with CSS only

Tags: html, css, grid

I see that masonry and its lookalikes can solve this problem but I'm looking for a CSS-only, unobtrusive solution.

I have a list of elements that I want to behave in the following manner:

- Each box takes up 33% or 200px, whichever is smaller
- When a box is clicked, it takes up 100% or 400px, whichever is smaller
- No gutters, 1px borders
- Quick animation on resize
- Centered elements
- No gutters = no blue in the example below
- Unobtrusive, css-only approach

Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to a library?  We only need to support "modern" browsers here.

Snippet of my attempt - it's not centering and you see lots of blue (my bigger concern is that when clicked, there's bottom gap):

```js
$(".event-block").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active-block')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active-block')
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active-block')
  }
})
```

```css
.event-block {
  width: 33%;
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.event-block:after {
  padding-top: 75%;
  /* 3:2 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.active-block {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 400px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Requirements</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Each box takes up 33% or 200px, whichever is smaller</li>
  <li>When a box is clicked, it takes up 100% or 400px, whichever is smaller</li>
  <li>No gutters, 1px borders</li>
  <li>Quick animation on resize</li>
  <li>Centered elements</li>
  <li>No gaps = no blue</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="event-block">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify are you happy to use javascript? the attempt you posted uses js but your question asks for css only?

Comment: @BenLonsdale - I'm happy to use JS to add/remove CSS classes for the sake of demonstration.

Comment: *Maybe* CSS Grid but otherwise no. the line-box model doesn't work that way.